# Android OCR Native library

Tags: java, android, ocr, native-methods

I am trying to develop a Android OCR app (for home use).

I had the idea to use the Asprise OCR in the app but instead of the windows version I was gonna use the Linux version.

The problem is, I don't know how to handle the native libraries. They have the extension .SH
I'm developing in Eclipse.

Comment: @MarcB: You mean a shell script. Not specifically bash.

Answer (score 3):

Google recently released an OCR API, so you probably want to use that:
https://developers.google.com/vision/text-overview

Just add the following line to your dependecies:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:9.2.0'
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you to use Android Studio instead of Eclipse and related to the OCR library, you could use Tesseract, which is an open source library developed by Google.

Here you have more information and a practical example to follow:

https://solidgeargroup.com/ocr-on-android

Answer (score 1):

That reference may help you:

http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/

Hope this helps

---

Update 13/04/17: Removed the [broken link](http://www.harshadura.net/2011/12/making-simple-ocr-android-app-using.html), will put it back if it goes up again.

Comment: That doesn not make any sense to me at all. Read both of them but I have no idea what to do.